# Actually installing Grape imports

Tags: groovy, import, groovy-grape

I have a script that I quickly put up using a `@Grab` annotation to import a package - namely [HttpBuilder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/home.html). Now I would like to actually install HttpBuilder and get rid of the annotation before putting the script in production - I do not want to grab the dependency dynamically on the prod server.

How do I actually tell Grape to install the dependency once and for all? Is there even a way to do this? If not, how should I install this package before deploying?

**EDIT** Following the advice from tim_yates, I donwloaded all teh JARs from HttpBuilder website, and added them to the classpath. But, when I run `groovy -cp dependencies/* myApp.groovy` what I get is a bunch of errors like

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
/path/to/dependencies/httpclient-4.0.3.jar: 1: unexpected char: 0x3 @ line 1, column 3.
   PK
     ^
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the [Downloads page](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/download.html) for HttpBuilder, you can follow the links in the first paragraph and download the `http-builder-xxx-all.zip` for the release you want...

Expand this, and it contains the jar, and the dependency jars in the `dependencies` folder

Then, just add them to the classpath in the usual way and get rid of the `@Grab` line

Comment: @Andrea looks like there's something wrong with the download...one sec, I'll check...

Comment: @Andrea I just tried with the 0.5.3 [snapshot from here](http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/org/codehaus/groovy/modules/http-builder/http-builder/0.5.3-SNAPSHOT/http-builder-0.5.3-20111229.173616-1-all.zip), unzipped it, and ran `groovy -cp http-builder-0.5.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:dependencies/* test.groovy` (where test.groovy is [this script here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/index.html)), and it all worked fine...

Comment: Ok, let me try again with another download

Comment: Ok, it turns out that the problem was that I actually moved http-builder inside dependencies and ran `groovy -cp dependencies/* test.groovy`. What is wrong with it? Excuse me, I am a newbie on the JVM

Comment: @Andrea Ahhhh...  When you just have a path with a wildcard, the shell jumps in and replaces the wildcard with the expanded list of files (separated by space), so you end up with the command: `groovy -cp dependencies/a.jar dependencies/b.jar ...etc... test.groovy` So groovy tries to load the `b.jar` as your script, and falls on its face.  Try: `groovy -cp "dependencies/*" test.groovy` By quoting the -cp parameter, it should make it into the JVM as it is, without bash trying to be helpful and messing it up...